# Scrollbar in facebook like box

Tags: facebook, scrollbar, facebook-likebox

I am using facebook like box in my website and I re-sized the height of the iframe. Now the scrollbar is visible partially (bottom arrow button missing). not sure what's the problem and any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How did you added your "like box", `iframe` or Facebook `div`? and what do you want? remove the scroll-bar or make the bottom arrow displayed

Comment: in a iframe.. .here is the code that i am using: <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2XXXXXXXX4&amp;width&amp;height=300&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;header=true&amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow: hidden; height:300px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>